# Show feedback for errors but not success in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlcl

In SQL Developer, `set feedback off` hides all the output irrespective of error messages.

I want to hide only the messages that are success and show the error messages.

This is how SQL*Plus behaves. Is the same behaviour possible in SQL Developer and SQLcl?

Comment: It doesn't suppress error messages in SQL\*Plus. (It does in SQL Developer, at least in recent versions...)

Comment: Ohh thanks.. I was trying in sqldeveloper and I thought it would do the same in sqlplus.

Comment: It might be useful to add the version of SQL Developer you're using to the question. I've seen this in 17.3 and 17,4; I'm pretty sure it used to work the way you want, but I don't know when it changed. (The design philosophy is generally that these things should work the same as SQL\*Plus, so I suspect this isn't intentional...)

Comment: I am using SQL Developer  17.3.0.271

Comment: I've popped a question off to the Product Manager for comment.  Will keep you posted.